# Prove that '$\int_E f_n\leq M$ implies $\int_E f\leq M$ ' is equivalent to Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The following question is taken from Royden Real Analysis $4$th edition, Chapter $4,$ question $20.$

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions that converges to $f$ pointwise on $E.$
>       Let $M\geq 0$ be such that $\int_E f_n\leq M$ for all $n.$
>       Show that $\int_E f\leq M.$
>       Verify that this property is equivalent to the statement of Fatou's Lemma.

I have proven that $\int_E f\leq M.$ But I have no idea on how to tackle second part.

After some googling, I found a [solution in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375375/verifying-fatous-lemma), which goes as follows:

> Let $(f_n,n\in\Bbb N)$ be a sequence of measurable integrable functions and $a_N:=\inf_{k\geqslant N}\int f_kd\mu$. Working with the sequence $(f_n,n\geqslant N)$ (for which the sequence of integrals has the same $\liminf$ as those of the whole sequence), one can see that that $\int fd\mu\leqslant a_N$ for each $N$. Now take the limit $\lim_{N\to +\infty}$.

**Questions:**

$(1)$ What is a motivation of considering $a_N:=\inf_{k\geq N}\int f_k d\mu?$

$(2)$ Why does $\int f d\mu\leq a_N$ for each $N?$

Comment: The motivation for $a_N$ is that it is part of the definition of $\liminf$. That $\int f \ d\mu \leq a_N$ follows from the fact that the subsequence $(f_k)_{k \geq N}$ is itself a sequence, so that the conclusion follows from the hypothesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int\inf_{k\geq N}f_{k}d\mu\leq\int f_{k}d\mu$ for all $k\geq N$, so $\displaystyle\int\inf_{k\geq N}f_{k}d\mu\leq a_{N}\leq M:=\sup_{N}a_{N}$ for all $N=1,2,...$. Now $\inf_{k\geq N}f_{k}\rightarrow\liminf_{n}f_{n}$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$, by the result, then $\displaystyle\int\liminf_{n}f_{n}d\mu\leq M$, and it is actually the case that $M=\sup_{N}a_{N}=\sup_{N}\inf_{k\geq N}\displaystyle\int f_{k}d\mu=\liminf_{n}\displaystyle\int f_{n}d\mu$.

Comment: The reason for that... I would say, because it is part of the form of Fatou's Lemma...

Comment: So I think your number 2) does not necessarily hold, but I switch to another strategy.